# "allow executing file as program" box was already marked in the files I downloaded

Tags: security

I learned that, in order to install a program, one should make the downloaded file executable by going to its properties and marking the "allow executing file as program" box.

I understand this as a security feature. 
Here comes the problem, I downloaded a game (www.tibia.com) for Linux, and when I went to mark the "allow executing file as program" box, it was already marked.

I thought it was a Ubuntu thing, and tried to download the same game on Fedora, but it was the same thing.

Is it not a problem for security? It reminds me of some problems other OS face with double-clicking file to install virus.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few important sub-questions, here, so I'll attack this piece by piece:

### What makes a file "executable"?

Linux and Unix systems determine whether a file is executable by examining the "execute" (`-x`) bit of the file permissions.

If you go to a terminal and run `ls -l Downloads` (replace "Downloads" with the location of your downloaded files, if different). You may see something like this:

```
total 13557K
-rwxrwxr-x  1 Matthew Matthew  13557241 Apr 11 04:11 Downloaded_Game
```

The `x`s in the first column mean the file is executable by the owner (Matthew), the group (Matthew), and world (everyone). (The `r` and `w` correspond to "readable" and "writable", respectively.)

### OK, what is setting the "execute" bit?

Whenever a file is created on a Linux system, the process (program) that is creating the file (in your case, most likely your web browser) must specify the file permissions. These permissions are then usually *but not always* limited by the user's `umask`. See the manual page for `umask` for more information on this sub-question.

### What difference does this make to security?

You may have a point in questioning whether there is a potential security risk in marking downloaded files as executable. However, Linux and Unix systems in general are historically noted for getting in the user's way as little as possible.

That being said, Linux and Unix systems also inherently limit the damage that executable programs can do, at least when those programs are run by a regular user (and not as the superuser, root). A program that deletes your home directory could likely still ruin your lunch break, but as is the expectation of responsible users of *any* operating system, you are ultimately the one responsible for ensuring you only run programs that you trust, or can verify yourself.

In other words, even with the execute bit on, *you* still have to make the decision to run the program. More importantly, even without the execute bit, *the file can still be executed,* so it would be false to consider the lack of an execute bit more "secure" in any significant sense.

### Conclusion

In short, don't worry overmuch about a file's executable status. As emphasized above, be careful what you download in the first place, and verify what you download before you run it. Where possible, use trusted sources like the Ubuntu apt repository.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't worry very much about viruses, but I am very scared of keyloggers.